# OpenCV Error: "OpenCV was not initialized correctly. Application will be shut down"

Tags: android, opencv

I m Using OpenCV 2.4.8 for android. I tried to run the OpenCV Samples on bluestack but it shows the following message::

OpenCV error: "OpenCV was not initialized correctly. Application will be shut down".

Comment: I'm using OpenCV 2.4.9 and I have same problem!

Comment: I am facing this problem while running my app on Lenovo A6000. Though the app runs perfectly on Mi3. On Lenovo, I tried installing all possible apks, i.e. armv7, armv7 neon etc but no success. While on Mi3, the play store version of the OpenCV manager was enough.

Answer (score 4):

You should install OpenCV manager OpenCV_2.4.9_Manager_2.18_x86.apk instead of other OpenCV managers.

Answer (score 0):

I searched several answers but I found that downloading appropriate OpenCV Manager was the best way.

1. visit http://opencv.org/
2. go to download page
3. find appropriate library version (which you've used in android project)
4. unzip file, and you will see 'apk file'(there are opencv manager)
5. select suitable apk file (if you don't know what's suitable, try every single of them)