# opencv was not initialised correctly Application will be shut down

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

**opencv was not initialised correctly Application will be shut down**

> i downloaded FacialRecognisition project from this link [https://github.com/ayuso2013/face-recognition] and imported it to eclipse .....
>   **OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk**
>
> i have ran App on decvice asus zenfone4 **version 4.4.2** and it is working fine but.... i tried to run it on another devices (**version: jellybean ,lollipop**....etc) but its shows an error **opencv was not initialised correctly Application will be shut down**    try others versions oencv manager too...but failed

**sdk**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>`
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="23"/>
```

Comment: This link may help you...
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472173/opencv-error-opencv-was-not-initialized-correctly-application-will-be-shut-do)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I've installed the `OpenCV_2.4.11_Manager_2.20_armv7a-neon-android8.apk` ([link](https://github.com/lasarobotics/opencv-builds/find/master)) on my samsung s6 and it works.